# How to create a shortcut to a particular command in command prompt?

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt, appletviewer

Is it possible to create something like a desktop shortcut that I could double click to run a particular command that I would normally type out in command prompt? Here is one that I want to make a shortcut of:

`C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java>appletviewer ButtonExample.html`

I asked this on Yahoo Answers because I thought it would be a little basic for Stack Overflow and one person said to create a batch file like so:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java>appletviewer ButtonExample.html"
```

I did this but all it does is open a command prompt window.

Comment: What is the purpose of `>` in the above?

Comment: It's where the directory part of the prompt ends and you can start typing, usually.

Comment: I'm just entering it as I see it in Command Prompt. So C:\Users\jdave....Java is the directory I'm in and then it has the '>' after which I can type in my command

Comment: New -> Shortcut -> (type) cmd /c C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java>appletviewer GifExample.html

Comment: Not sure how to edit the question but what I meant to say is appletviewer ButtonExample.html both times.

Comment: @Joey I thought it was output redirection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your batch file should look something like this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Windows\System32\
start notepad.exe C:\Users\"user1"\test.txt
```

Replace the "user1" with your username or give the proper path to your application.

Make sure that **appletviewer** takes the type of parameter that you are passing it.

Comment: This worked! Thanks, and thank you to everybody who answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a shortcut with

```
C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java\appletviewer ButtonExample.html
```

Comment: I tried this but all it does is open up the appletviewer. Doesn't open the html file that runs the Java applet.

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't look correct, try this:

```
C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java\appletviewer GifExample.html
```

Ensure that appletviewer.exe exists in this location.

Comment: `start` is a built-in command of `cmd`, not a program. So you need to run it through `cmd`. But you don't need it at all here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set java bin directory in environment variable path. Use following batch :

```
@echo off
cd  "C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java"
appletviewer GifExample.html
```

Comment: This also would work, I wish I could Vote Up you but I don't have enough Rep yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on Desktop > New > Shortcut. Enter Location

```
appletviewer GifExample.html
```

Click Next, enter name of shortcut, click Finish. You're done.

By the way, the > you see on the command prompt is **not** part of the command. The actual command starts **after** the > symbol.

Also, the 'appletviewer' program **probably doesn't** reside in `C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java`. The above is correct if you can already run appletviewer from any folder in the command prompt. If you do `C:\Users\jdave\Documents\Java\appletviewer GifExample.html` it may not work at all!